# MVC 4 Web API configure the max size of response sent?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, queue

I have an MVC 4 Web API in C# 4.5. 
I have a get method that returns values from a queue.

The queue holds a List of Custom objects.

```
<pre><code>
 Queue<List<MyObject>> mQueue;
</pre></code>
```

The queue can have a max value of 50. so basically the queue can hold a max value of 50 lists. The lists usually hold about 100 - 400 entities. so 50 * 400 = 20,000 <-- probably about the max +2000
the minimum case would be 5000.

Now lets say the queue has 50 lists and I hit my web service to dump the contents to me in a web response. the response might be pretty damn big.

I can't seem to get the service to return more than 1.32-1.39 mb of data back to me. Is this due to a max size of returned response? If so how can I get around this? BTW the response is json formatted. I'm hosting in IIS 7 as well.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions, such as exceeding "MaxJsonLength"?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an older version of the code where the queue max size was set to 5. oh well everybody is granted one DURP moment on mondays.